# Relative Primes and Congruence

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose that $a$ and $n$ are relatively prime.

Prove that there is an integer $b$ such that $ab\equiv 1\pmod n$ .

Comment: What do you know, Bezout, Euler phi?

Comment: I've tried to use the fact that there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $xa + yn = 1$

Comment: Great! Reduce your equation mod n and see what you get!

Comment: Sorry, what exactly do you mean by reducing the equation mod n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\gcd(a,n)=1$, then $\exists \ b,d \in \mathbb Z$ such that $ab+nd=1$. Reducing the equation modulo $n$, we get $$ab \equiv 1 \pmod n$$

**Further clarification:** Since $\gcd(a,n)=1$, $1$ can be written as a linear combination of $a$ and $n$. So, $ab+nd=1$. We can rewrite this as $nd=1-ab$. We see that $n$ divides $1-ab$, i.e. $n \mid 1-ab$. So, $1 \equiv ab \pmod n$, and since congruence is an equivalence relation, we can rewrite this as $ab \equiv 1 \pmod n$

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by reducing the equation modulo n?

Comment: I've edited my answer.

Comment: Reducing modulo $n$ basically means seeing what the remainder of something is after dividing by $n$. For example, let's reduce $a=n$ modulo $n$. $n$ divided $n$ leaves a remainder of $0$, so we see right away that $a \equiv 0 \pmod n$.

Comment: $\ j = k\,\Rightarrow\, j\equiv k\pmod n\,\Rightarrow\, \bar j\equiv \bar k \pmod n,\ $ if $\,\bar j\equiv j,\, \bar k\equiv k\pmod n.\,$ That's what is meant by reducing the equation mod $\,n.\ $ Thus $\,\ ab+nd = 1\,\Rightarrow\, ab\equiv 1\pmod n\,$ by $\,ab+nd\equiv ab.\,$ Or, proceeding more directly we have  that:  $\  nd = 1-ab\,\Rightarrow\,d\mid 1-ab\,\Rightarrow\,1\equiv ab\pmod d\ $ *by definition* of congruence @db2791